# case : check if field A exist in field B

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, sql

[image: Data]

i have a data extension with the first 3 fields : Id, `Email_source1` and `Email_source2`. i want to create the field named X. The goal is to check if `Email_source1` is in `Email_source2`. Does someone know how to build this by using a case or something else?

I don't know how to think this:

```
select t1.*,
case when Email_source1 in (select Id,Email_source1,Email_source2 from table_1 t2 left join table_1 t3 on t2.Email_source1=t3.Email_source1) then 'yes' 
else 'no'
end as X
from table_1 t1
```

What I forgot to notice is that a same email address can exist for two different Id.

Thank you for help or any suggestion

Comment: does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to overcomplicate it with a subquery in the `CASE-WHEN` statement, it is enough to simply compare two fields like that -

```sql
SELECT
Id,
Email_source1,
Email_source2,

CASE
    WHEN Email_source1 = Email_source2 THEN 'True'
    ELSE 'False'
END AS X

FROM Data_Extension
```